# How do I cover the test cases for useState hook in React Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have been writing code for a reusable date range picker which lets users set **startDate** and **endDate** and comes with an Apply button and dropdown options including ( **Today**, **Tomorrow**, **This Month**, etc ) for filling up the selector automatically .

While the basic functionalities are covered by the test cases written, it shows just 50% of the test cases are covered.

The uncovered line numbers are,

```
const onStartDateChange = value => {
    setStartAndEndDate(prev, { ...prev, startDate: value });
    setIsButtonDisabled(false);
};
```

Here, `jest --coverage` shows the line `setStartAndEndDate(...` not being covered by the test cases.

A little note is, the onStartDateChange is not coming from the props but resides inside the component itself.

**The usage for the component is like,**

`<DateRangePicker enableTime onApplyClick={onApplyButtonClickMock} />`

How do I cover the the function that is called when the date is picked from the calendar or ( from the dropdown ) startDate date picker is .

Minimal Reproducible Scenario:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sn2uhv

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [startAndEndDate, setStartAndEndDate] = useState({
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1)),
  });

  const onStartTimeChange = (e) => {
    // How do I cover the line number 12 below...
    setStartAndEndDate((prev) => ({ ...prev, startDate: e.target.value }));
  };

  console.log(startAndEndDate);

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={onStartTimeChange} name="start-date" type="date" />
      <input name="end-date" type="date" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Use the testing library to simulate user interactions that trigger the callback. Hard to say more without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: @ggorlen , thank you for your suggestion. I have updated the question with a scenario similar to the problem faced.

Comment: @ggorlen ,thank you.just updated the question with the code too.